# Can I use Local Sockets on a Windows Operating System? - C++ / Boost

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, boost, boost-asio

Can I create a `boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket` on a Windows Operating System? I know it is supposed to be a 'UNIX' socket, but does Windows not support this?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood that correctly, `boost::asio::local::stream_protocol` is POSIX specific. Windows itself is no POSIX conform environment, but there are POSIX enviroments for Windows out there, namely [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). But you will not be able to distribute these applications without distributing the environment as well.

In some cases, especially when Unix is your primary target platform, and you are offering a Windows version out of generosity, this may be acceptable.

Otherwise you should think about ways of getting around the functionalities which are explicitly marked as non-portable.

Comment: Unix(-like) is kinda my target platform but I just love developing on a Windows Computer. I'll just use Linux I guess.

Comment: @Binero unfortunately I cannot test whether Windows with Cygwin would work out; I don't own a Windows computer.

Comment: Cygwin does support AF_UNIX, but transparently implements it as AF_INET if memory services. It does not have the exact same security semantics as AF_UNIX would on an actual Linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

From the boost docs, you can test for [`BOOST_ASIO_HAS_LOCAL_SOCKETS`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html) to determine if they are supported on your local operating system. Considering `AF_UNIX` is not supported on Windows, it would seem likely that this definition is not available under your standard Windows environment.